# How to remove quotes with grep and cut in one command

Tags: linux, grep, cut

This is what I do currently:

```
pass1=$(grep DB_PASSWORD /home/user/public_html/wp-config.php | cut -d ' ' -f3)
# it echoes 'password' with start and end single quotes
pass=${pass1:1:-1}
# it remove single quotes from start and end
```

But I want to combine these two commands in a single go.

I tried some wrong commands which showed me the help of `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `awk`:

```
pass=$(awk -F"'" '/DB_PASSWORD/{print $4}' /home/user/public_html/wp-config.php)
```

I simply defined `'` to be the field separator, which makes the password the 4th field.

Comment: Thanks, but it prints everything has single quotes, but I want to separate db password, user and db name in three different variables.

Comment: Sorry, fixing it now.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` you can match the whole line and match the DB_PASSWORD field between the double quotes, and capture the inner text of the  next field between double quotes in a capture group.

In the replacement use capture group 1.

```
pass=$(sed -En "s/^.*'DB_PASSWORD'[^']*'([^']+)'.*/\1/p" /home/user/public_html/wp-config.php)
```

Or ss your fields are separated by spaces, you could also get the 3rd field using `awk`, where `\x27` matches a single quote which can be replaced by an empty string:

```
pass=$(awk '/DB_PASSWORD/{gsub("\x27", "", $3);print $3}' /home/user/public_html/wp-config.php)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it prints everything has single quotes, but I want to separate db password, user and db name in three different variables.

Comment: Yes, but I'm grepping `DB_PASSWORD` and I am trying to only grep this and advance with no quotes.

Comment: @Saeed Ok, let met update it

Comment: @Saeed The awk command now matches on DB_PASSWORD, and also the sed variant.